# routing in automation in cypress, localStorage getting cleared thats why getting 401 error

Tags: automation, cypress

I am doing automation but facing issue of localStorage getting cleared . Means in my project, after login then " localStorage.getItem() " getting display in console or in Application local Storage . But while routing in same project then localStorage getting cleared and thats why getting 401 issue. Please give me solution

Comment: I have similar issue if I use `cy.reload()`. Check if you use sich

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you’re clearing localStorage whenever you do a page navigation? Without code it’s difficult to say for sure.